# JavaScript forEach. String elements to date

Tags: javascript, foreach

I have an array of strings **scheduleDates**:

```
0:"24.04.2016, 11:53"
1:"12.04.2016, 10:07"
2:"13.04.2016, 9:45"
```

I need to replace the **string** elements to **Date** type in the same array.

I tried:

```
scheduleDates.forEach(function (date) {
    var currDate = date.split(', ')[0];
    var currTime = date.split(', ')[1];
    var hours = currTime.split(':')[0];
    var minutes = currTime.split(':')[1];
    var year = currDate.split('.')[2];
    var month = currDate.split('.')[1];
    var day = currDate.split('.')[0];
    var newDate = new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes);
    date = newDate;
});
```

It doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

```
var scheduleDates = ["24.04.2016, 11:53","12.04.2016, 10:07","13.04.2016, 9:45"];

scheduleDates = scheduleDates.map(function (date) {
    var currDate = date.split(', ')[0];
    var currTime = date.split(', ')[1];
    var hours = currTime.split(':')[0];
    var minutes = currTime.split(':')[1];
    var year = currDate.split('.')[2];
    var month = currDate.split('.')[1];
    var day = currDate.split('.')[0];
    return new Date(year, month-1, day, hours, minutes);
});
```

Comment: still Invalid Date

Answer (score 0):

`date` is a variable that is local to every function call. You're assigning to this local variable, not the position in the array.

An ugly fix is to assign the new value to the correct index. This is a bit hacky, and generally not what [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) is intended for.

```
scheduleDates.forEach(function (date, index) {
    var currDate = date.split(', ')[0];
    var currTime = date.split(', ')[1];
    var hours = currTime.split(':')[0];
    var minutes = currTime.split(':')[1];
    var year = currDate.split('.')[2];
    var month = currDate.split('.')[1];
    var day = currDate.split('.')[0];
    var newDate = new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes);

    scheduleDates[index] = newDate;
});
```

You could instead use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), and assign the resulting array back into your variable.

```
scheduleDates = scheduleDates.map(function (date) {
    // ...

    return newDate;
});
```

Or roll your own destructive map, to make things a little easier.

```
function mapd (array, block) {
  var length = array.length;

  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    array[i] = block(array[i], i);
  }
}

mapd(scheduleDates, function (date) {
  // ...

  return newDate;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should use **map** instead of forEach. It better fits your purpose.

Here is what I would do (by following your initial thoughts):

```
function toDateObject(date) {
    var currDate = date.split(', ')[0];
    var currTime = date.split(', ')[1];
    var hours = currTime.split(':')[0];
    var minutes = currTime.split(':')[1];
    var year = currDate.split('.')[2];
    var month = currDate.split('.')[1];
    var day = currDate.split('.')[0];
    return new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes);
}

var scheduleDates = ["24.04.2016, 11:53","12.04.2016, 10:07","13.04.2016, 9:45"].map(toDateObject);
```

Array.prototype.map applies the function given as argument to each element of the array and the collects all the result in a new array which is the result.

In this case it receives an array of strings, applies the toDateObject function to each of them and then returns a new array of the results of that function calls.

Read more about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map